# How should I check for unique values while building a Graph?

Tags: java, neo4j, unique, nodes, neo4j-ogm

I'm using neo4j OGM for communicating with my neo4j database. i'm trying to store a json collection with data. This collection contains a lot of duplicate data. Is there a way to ask the OGM to filter the duplicate data for me so that my graph does not contains duplicate data?

If the OGM does not contains this functionality what is the best way to filter this data or what is the best way to check if data already exist in the database?

Comment: How do you determine that the json is duplicated ? do you have some kind of id or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Cypher [MERGE](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-merge.html) clause (instead of `CREATE`) to avoid creating duplicates. You should read the documentation to understand how to use `MERGE` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the mapping capabilities of the OGM, then you'll need to load entities from the graph first, and then either create or update them depending on whether they exist or not. The OGM does not have any "merge" functionality at the moment.

The other option is to do this directly via Cypher queries, and then, you should use Cypher MERGE as suggested by @cybersam.